Which one of Sion Sono's movies is this scene taken from?
Which one of Sion Sono's movies is this scene depicting a young girl in a lake of blood taken from?


The action film Why Don't You Play in Hell? from 2013.

There's a war going on, but that won't stop the inexperienced but eager wannabe film crew The F@#% Bombers from following their dreams of making the ultimate action epic. Ten years ago, yakuza mid-boss Ikegami led an assault against rival don Muto. Now, on the eve of his revenge, all Muto wants to do is complete his masterpiece, a feature film with his daughter in the starring role, before his wife is released from prison. And The F@#% Bombers are standing by with the chance of a lifetime: to film a real, live yakuza battle to the death on 35mm.

Here's the scene [Warning: This scene is literally a girl watersliding in a pool of blood]:



